# Yeoman angular grunt-serve vs http-serve

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, yeoman, httpserver

I've just used Yeoman to create an Angular project that looks great when I run `grunt serve`. But then I decided to view it by running `http-server`, and the page gets displayed without the formatting and without the images. Does anyone know why that is and if I'll run into this issue when I push it up to my web hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I had to run grunt to build the project which fixes the references and places a distribution uglified version of the project in a dist folder. This ran just fine on my other server.

Answer (score 0):

**"Does anyone know why that is and if I'll run into this issue when I push it up to my web hosting server?"**

Yes, you will run into this problem on your web hosting server. 
`grunt-serve` serves the app used the setup on your local machine. 
`http-server` mimics how a real web hosting server would evaluate your references.

My development routine is to use `grunt-serve` until I have a working version and then use `http-server` to test it out and see if it would work before I push it to my web hosting server. As @cdavid mentioned, running `grunt build` from your `dist` directory should be sufficient for general dependency issues.